# Storing an array with an array - Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, debugging, object, swift3

So I am attempting to upload information to Firebase through a query, and I am getting stuck on some of this logic. My issue is that when I try storing the object I have created into an array, I am getting an error that says I cannot subscript [[any]] with [any]. Now what I am trying to accomplish, is rather than have a bunch of if-else statements, to use a for-loop to run through which array of data i should be placing the object within. I am just getting a little stuck on how I should append it correctly, and would love the assistance!

My error is `"Cannot subscript a value of type [Any] with an index of type Any"`

Here are my data structures:

```
/** Setting up the Data **/

    var genresLabelIndex = ["Fiction", "Poetry", "NonFiction", "Science"]

    var fiction = [InformationForFeed]()
    var poetry = [InformationForFeed]()
    var nonFiction = [InformationForFeed]()
    var science = [InformationForFeed]()
    var allGenresData = [[Any]]()

    func getData() {



        for genre in genresLabelIndex {

            let dbReference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("genres").child(genre)
            let query = dbReference.queryOrderedByKey().queryLimited(toFirst: 3)

            query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot : FIRDataSnapshot) in

                if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

                    for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [FIRDataSnapshot] {

                        let item = snap.value as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject?>
                        let data = InformationForFeed(dictionary: item as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)
                        for i in (self.allGenresData) {
                            self.allGenresData[i].append(data)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print("This snap shot doesnt have any data")
                }
            })
        }

        print(allGenresData)

    }
```

My error is at line `self.allGenresData[i].append(data)`
Within my Init() I am doing the following:

```
allGenresData = [self.fiction, self.poetry, self.nonFiction, self.science]
getData()
```

Comment: What error meesage do you get?

Comment: "Cannot subscript a value of type [Any] with an index of type Any"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're storing each element of `allGenresData` in the variable `i`:

```
for i in (self.allGenresData) {
```

However, you're then treating `i` as if it is an index into the array:

```
self.allGenresData[i].append(data)
```

Unfortunately `i` here contains the sub-array itself, not the index. To solve this, you want to assign `i` to the actual indices into the array. You can do that like this:

```
for i in self.allGenresData.indices {
```

The `i` variable should then be suitable for subscripting the array.

Comment: I just realized that this does not correctly achieve what I am trying to do, this does not store the information into the arrays that are sub-arrayed within allGenresData, rather it stores it all within allGenresData, as when I print out the count for any of the arrays, they return 0, the error itself is solved however

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
var dataArray = [InformationForFeed]()
let data = InformationForFeed(dictionary: item as Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)
dataArray.append(data)
for i in (self.allGenresData) {
    self.allGenresData[i].append(dataArray)
}
```

*You are trying to put `InformationForFeed` in `[[InformationForFeed]]`.

Comment: Same error except it is now [[Any]] cannot subscript into [any]